# TypeError when Trying to Index into Numpy Array

Tags: python, database, numpy

Data consists of 10 values and I want to expand it so the dimensions are equal.

```py
import numpy as np
W = 17
cen = 80
dim = 20
E= np.zeros((dim))
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = E((cen - np.round(W*2.21*2)) + np.round(i*2.21*2))
    print(data)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

but it shows output if i remove `E`.

In MATLAB its written like this

```
W = 17
cen = 80
dim = 20
E=zeros(1,dim);
for i=1:length(data)
    E((center-round(W*2.21*2))+round(i*2.21*2))=data(i);
end
```

Why am I getting this TypeError?

Comment: MATLAB indexing is with `()`, Python indexing is with `[]`.  You have that right with `data[i]`.

Comment: why it shows error message ?

Comment: You can't treat a numpy array as though it were a function!

Comment: You should've got different error. `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

When you call E, you must access to its element by [] e not by (), in python.

```
E[(cen - np.round(W*2.21*2)) + np.round(i*2.21*2)]
```

Comment: @ Roberto Bellarosa, I tried as you suggested then it shows message.                                    IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Evidently the index derived from the computation within the square brackets of E returns a non-integer number. I suggest you review the calculation. Or try to cast all to integer.

Comment: Tried using E[np.around(cen - np.round(W*2.21*2)) + np.round(i*2.21*2))] stilö same issue. output is not integer . it shows with ne decimal. tried np.around to get integer value but still not working